# Add path ruby on rails in vuejs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, vue.js, vuejs2, ruby-on-rails-5

i'm new in vuejs and ruby on rails, i have to add this path

```
<%=profile_path(@profile)%>
```

I made a link with the full name of the user and when he clicks his name he must send me to his profile:

```html
                 <a
                      v-for="(link, key_l) in links"
                      :key="key_l"
                      :href="link.href"
                      :target="link.target"
                 >
                      {{ teammate.profile.name }}
                      {{ teammate.profile.last_name }}
                 </a>
```

```js
 data: () => {
    return {
      links: [{ href: "<%=profile_path(@profile)%>", target: "_blank" }],
    };
  },
```

but the path is in ruby on rails, how can I add it in vuejs ?

Answer (score 0):

Where you are translating from rails to js you need it to generate a url not a path to be interpreted by rails.

Try sending profile_url(@profile) instead as this will generate what you are expecting.

Comment: in `routes.rb?`

Comment: Sorry, I have edited my answer for a little more clarity. To be more precise, you need to replace: href: "<%=profile_path(@profile)%>", target: "_blank" }] with something like:

href: "#{profile_url(@profile)}", target: "_blank" }]

This will still draw from your routes file providing you have your profile resource set.